# Is Motif/UIL Model-View-ViewModel?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, motif

I'm trying to wrap my head around what this pattern entails (other than just "I'm using a recent Microsoft GUI toolikt"). The [MVVM wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page seems to explain it as a separation of the parts of the system that represent the model and the part that represent the graphical view of it, with a bit in the middle converting between the two. It also implies that Microsoft invented this concept for WPF.

However, I'm not seeing what the difference is between this and what [UIL](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~rth/cs/cs177/s98/IntroUIL2.html) has done for [Motif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_%28widget_toolkit%29) since the 1980's.

So is MVVM just *patternese* for schemes like Motif's user code/UIL/MRM setup, or is there something more to it?

Answer (score 1):

MVVM is a concept, or "patternese," as you coined, for one method of separating the user interface from the algorithms that produce the data you want to visualize.

I wouldn't say, though, that UIL is a good example of this. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVVM), MVVM doesn't require a separate user interface language, but it can help. Motif was never designed to perform a complete separation of UI from business logic. All UIL does is specify templates of a UI widget hierarchy that can be fetched multiple times, reused whenever and wherever, and pre-set various things. You still need to provide code for the callbacks to make things happen, including changing color and performing other operations above & beyond what UIL permits.